# What is includeBounds in ReadRaw method(from OPC Foundation libraries for .NET)?

Tags: .net, opc

I use opc libraries for .NET by OPC Foundation.
Method ReadRaw in the Server class(Opc.Hda namespace).
What does the "bool includeBounds" variable do?

```
public ItemValueCollection[] ReadRaw(
      Time startTime,
      Time endTime,
      int maxValues,
      bool includeBounds,
      ItemIdentifier[] items)
    {
      if (this.m_server == null)
        throw new NotConnectedException();
      return ((IServer) this.m_server).ReadRaw(startTime, endTime, maxValues, includeBounds, items);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defines that possible samples corresponding to startTime and endTime are included in the results, i.e. 'startTime <= t <= endTime'. If it is false only samples for 'startTime < t < endTime' are included.